# Delete rows in dataframe where a name value in dataframe column equals to the value in a list

Tags: python

**Dataframe name is df_buysellrcds:**

[image]

**Values in list. Name is remove_list**

[image]

Hi all,

Below is my code logic. I want to loop the 5 records in remove_list to remove rows in df_buysellrcds if the Stock column value equals to the value in List, and value in Type column equals to 'Buy'.

```
for name in remove_list:
    for i, row in df_buysellrcds:
        if row["Stock"] == name and row["Type"]=="Buy":
            df_actualHoldings = df_buysellrcds.drop(df_buysellrcds.index[i])
```

However I got this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-10-a399d857a077>", line 2, in <module>
    for i, row in df_buysellrcds:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any ideas how should I improve my code?

My objective is to

1. Keep all rows with Type = 'Buy' where Stock value is not in the List
2. Keep all row with Type = 'Sell'
3. Remove rows with Type = 'Buy' if the Stock value exists in the list
   For example, first 2 records are remove but 3rd record retains for Stock value 'Genting'

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `df.loc[(~df.Stock.isin(remove_list)) & (df.type=='BUY')]` instead of all of your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're deleting rows while iterating over the dataframe, a `ValueError` is raised. To overcome this for instance, simply keep track of the indices of the rows to be deleted. However in this situation, the expressiveness of `pandas` allows us to bypass the iteration.

To keep only the elements whose `Type` is not `Buy` *or* whose `Stock` is not present in `remove_list`,

```py
df_filtered = df[(df.Type != "Buy") | ~df.Stock.isin(remove_list)]
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but it removes all rows in dataframe where Type column has 'Buy' values. I added in some points in my original question for clarity. My objective is to remove rows if Type column has 'Buy' and Stock column value is in the List. If the Stock name is in the List but in dataframe the Type is 'Sell', I still want to retain in the dataframe.

Comment: Good point. You want to remove rows whose `Type` is `Buy` and whose `Stock` value is in `remove_list`. In other words you want to *keep* rows whose `Type` is *not* `Buy` *OR* whose `Stock` value is *not* in `remove_list`. I edited my answer to translate this into Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tend to rely on old school method of iteration to get things done. Python indeed makes coding easy with just 1 line but still hard for me to get used to it.